# Android Studio passing parameters to AsyncTask that is being fired in a loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-studio

I am loading some values into an array from an SQLite table.

```
On button click
    Read rows in table and put values from column(y) into array
    Array1 = (value(1), value(2), value(3))
    Loop through array
        param1 = value(x)
        execute AsyncTask
    next
end click

execute AsycnTask
    on pre execute
        Loading dialogue
    end pre execute 
    do in background
        parse html (url + param1)
        param2 = parse result
    end background

    on post execute
        update table set column1 = param2 where column2 = param1
    end post execute
end execute AsyncTask
```

The doInBackground takes a few seconds to fetch the data and although the UPDATE query does correctly fire for as many values in the array, the do in background will only ever use the param1 from the first value in the array. It never uses the next, and on, and on...

I am probably going about this totally wrong, so if someone could help with the logic please?

Comment: store it in your class which extends AsyncTask as a field and pass em to constructor ... also ... it is better to loop inside background (also update can be done from inside of background)  `new MyAsync(Array).execute()` .. `class MyAsync { MyAsync(argArray) {store:fieldArray = argArray} doInBackground{ loop:fieldArray{parse and update}}}`

Comment: Selvin, I have put the code inside the background and it is now working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help with this. 
:D

Comment: no problem :) remeber about onProgressUpdate: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...) if you wana inform UI about progress